# How to send FIN+ACK after HTTP GET request in C#?

Tags: c#, http, get, handshake

I sent a GET request, and now I want to end the connection by sending FIN+ACK to the server. I have no socket, just this:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse webResponse;
using (webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
{
    //myThings
}
//FIN+ACK
```

Somehow it does three way handshake but it doesn't end the connection.

Comment: This is all abstracted away from you by HTTP & the WebRequest, why do you need to do it/what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

FIN/ACK is on the TCP level, which is not available on this level.

You could POST something back to that url to indicate you've received everything.